# Get a value from a middleware to use it inside a function in another module in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created `authenticateUser` middleware inside authenticateUser.js,

```
async function authenticateUser(req, res, next) {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  if (!authHeader) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized access!' });

  }

  try {
    const accessToken = await authHeader.split(' ')[1];
    // Check if the user exists and has the same access token
// Verify the JWT access token and extract the payload
const payload = jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
   // const role = payload.role;
   const {email,uid, role} = payload;

   
    const user = await UserClient.findOne({ email });
    if (!user || user.accessToken !== accessToken) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized access!' });
    }
 

    // expose the user role , client Id from the payload object for further processing
    req.role = role;
    req.email = email;
    req.uid = uid;

    // Call the next middleware to continue with the request processing
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized access!' });
  }
}
```

Here, when I need to use email value in another router,let's say `router.get("/user",authenticateUser,async(req,res)=>{})`, I can use `const email= req.email; console.log(email)` to use email value in users.js module. **But my question is, when I need to use this email value inside a function, how can I do it?**

The function I need to use `email` value is below (in sites.js file);

```
    async function addSitesToUser() {
      try {
<-------Need to use email value here-------->
        const userData = await UserClient.findOne({email});
    
        if(!userData.siteList || userData.siteList.length === 0){
          const updatedSites = await UserClient.findOneAndUpdate(
            { email },
            { $push: { siteList: { $each: sites } } },
            { upsert: true,new: true }
          );
        } else{
          const existingSiteIds = userData.siteList.map(site => site.siteId);
          // console.log("**exist: "+existingSiteIds)
          const newSites = sites.filter(site => !existingSiteIds.includes(site.siteId));
          // console.log("**newsit: "+newSites)
          userData.siteList.push(...newSites);
          await userData.save();
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error adding sites');
      }
    }
```

I invoke this above function from index.js `await addSitesToUser();`

Comment: Can you please provide more clarity on this. When you say you want to use email inside a function which function are you talking about? Where does that function get invoked from?

Comment: @NrujalSharma I updated the above question. thank you!

Comment: isnt it possible to pass the request variable as your function's parameter, like `async function addSitesToUser(req)` ..?

Comment: @Ke_Sandaru passing the request object should work. I've posted a detailed answer below and also mentioned how you can avoid calling the DB again and again to get the user data. Let me know if that answers your question or if you were looking for something else. Thank you!

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti I tried it previously, but I thought to have some other scenario other than invoking the function inside a router. Now, I think it is impossible to do. We essentially need a router to get the payload comes through middleware. Am I correct?

Comment: @NrujalSharma It works. I think we should maintain a router, to invoke any function, inside that router which gets input data from a middleware  as you suggested me?

Comment: @Ke_Sandaru yes that is correct. REST APIs work on HTTP which is stateless. Hence everything that happens can essentially happen during the request-response cycle only, which goes through the route listener. Hence, you've to make the function call from within the router itself. Do accept the answer as a solution if it resolved your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the email as an input to the function

```
router.get("/user",authenticateUser,async(req,res)=>{
    await addSitesToUser(req.email)
})
```

But there's a better approach to this IMO.
You already fetched the user once while authenticating the request.
Just set the whole user object in the request so that you don't have to fetch it anywhere in the lifecycle of that particular request.
So, in the middleware, just do

```
req.user = user
```

And then pass the `req` object down the functions so that you can access the user from any function down the line

```
router.get("/user", authenticateUser, async (req, res) => {
  await addSitesToUser(req);
  // function body
});
```

And the inside the addSitesToUser function

```
async function addSitesToUser(req) {
      try {
        const userData = req.user;

        // do whatever you want to do
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error adding sites');
      }
    }
```